# What languages can be compiled to javascript?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What compilers target JavaScript runtimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976003/what-compilers-target-javascript-runtimes)

Like CoffeeScript.
I don't really like javascript, and it will be nice if I could replace it.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?

Comment: See also [What compilers target JavaScript runtimes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976003/what-compilers-target-javascript-runtimes)

Answer (score 6):

I like JavaScript, but the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) is an open source development kit for creating and maintaining complex JavaScript applications in Java. It includes a Java-to-JavaScript compiler.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite is [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), it can compile Flash, C++, PHP too...

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried these, but:

[MileScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/milescript-a-new-language-that-compiles-to-javascript)
[Java](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/java_to_javascript.html)
[Objective-J](http://objective-j.org/)
[C#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/)

Answer (score 2):

[Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) is like GWT, but for Python.  [Red](http://wiki.github.com/jessesielaff/red/) is a Ruby->JS translator.

Answer (score 2):

And now, Lisp! [See here](http://joeganley.com/code/jslisp.html).

Admittedly, the syntax for some of these implementations is a bit strange. [Jisp](http://www.ducklet.com/jisp/) uses square brackets instead of parentheses.

I'm not sure if "compiled" applies here; at least part of them seem to be interpreters running as JavaScript programs.

Answer (score 0):

F#; see [HTML5 Programming with F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/html5-programming-with-f)